# C#: Can't write values stored in list to console

Tags: c#, list, lambda

I have the following function that allows me to make REST request via this function:

```
static Observation GetData(string baseUrl, string provider, string key, string sensor)
        {
            var client = new RestClient(String.Format("{0}/data/{1}/{2}", baseUrl, provider, sensor));
            client.Timeout = -1;
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
            request.AddHeader("IDENTITY_KEY", key);
            IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
            Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
            
            var observationsModel = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SentiloResponse>(response.Content, options);
            Console.WriteLine("This is observationsModel:");
            Console.WriteLine(observationsModel);
            Console.WriteLine("This is the outcome of GetData:");
            Console.WriteLine(observationsModel.Observations.FirstOrDefault());
            return observationsModel.Observations.FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

The outcome from it is the following (see screenshot):
[image]

Now, from this point

In the next section I call GetData, I would like to select Value and Timestamp Variables to do other tasks, but I'm unable to (my attempts are in lines where myTest and myTest_2 are being declared):

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            configuration = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<SentiloConfig>(File.ReadAllText("configuration.json"), options);
            Console.WriteLine("Configuration Loaded");
            
            foreach(var componentMapping in configuration.ComponentMappings)
            {
                var inputComponent = componentMapping.InputComponent;
                Console.WriteLine("Getting data");
                var sensorsContent = inputComponent.Sensors.AsParallel().Select(s =>
                    new SensorContent{
                        Sensor = GetSensorString(s.SensorName),
                        Observations = new List<Observation>() {
                                
                            GetData(
                                    inputComponent.ServerUrl,
                                    inputComponent.Provider,
                                    inputComponent.Token,
                                    GetSensorString(s.SensorName)
                                    )
                                
                        }
                    }
                ).Where(s => s.Observations.First() != null).ToList();
                var myTest = sensorsContent.Select(s => s.Observations.First().Value).ToList();
                var myTest_2 = sensorsContent.Select(s => s.Observations.First().Value.ToList());
                Console.WriteLine(myTest.ToString());
                Console.WriteLine(myTest_2);
                Console.WriteLine("data retrieved");
                if (!sensorsContent.Any())
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("No sensor data for component {0} with sensors: {1}, check configuration", inputComponent.ComponentName, string.Join(",", inputComponent.Sensors.Select(s => s.SensorName)));
                    continue;
                }
                var sensorRequest = new SentiloPutRequest { Sensors = sensorsContent };
                    
            }
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(configuration.SendTime*1000);
            
        }
```

But the outcome of myTest and myTest_2 are the following:

> System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] System.Linq.Enumerable+SelectListIterator`2[SentiloSpoofer.SensorContent,System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Char]]

I'm thinking perhaps is best to call GetData outside of the Lambda and bypass these issues, but if I wanted to retrieve this data, what could be a good way to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just the way you are writing to the console. Use `string.Join` or a `foreach`.

Essentially, you are trying to magic the values out of a list. Technically `List<T>` doesn't have an *override* of `ToString()` that knows how you want to format it. It's up to you. So it just returns the type name (which is what you are seeing).

Try instead:

```
foreach(var value in myTest)
  Console.WriteLine(value);

// or
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",",myTest));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Michael! It worked. My issue is that I'm way too inexperienced with C#, the closest I've been to it has been C++, and after that only Python or Matlab. I must confess that I laughed a lot when you said that I was trying to magic the values, well, indeed my friend (I blame it on my experience with Python and other languages hahaha ;)). Ok, now back to being serious. This means that I'm successfully allocating these values into myTest var, right?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access a List as a String.
The values are there if you wanna show it in your console, just use an aggregate in your List.

Example:

```
var myTestString = myTest.Select(i => i).Aggregate((i, j) => i + "," + j);
Console.WriteLine(myTestString)

// Or

myTest.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x));
```

Comment: `Select(i=>i)` is pointless as it's not doing anything and `string.Join` is a better idea than using `Aggregate` as it handles creating the string in a more efficient way.